# Ionic 5 : How to setup custom webpack config?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, webpack, ionic5

I am trying to setup a custom webpack config to my ionic 5 app,
there is nothing about that in ionic 5 documentation, so I followed ionic 3 doc.

In my package.json I add script and config like this:

```
 "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build:apk": "ionic cordova build android",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "private": true,
  "config": {
    "ionic_webpack": "custom.webpack.config.js"
  },
```

when I run "ionic serve" I got this error:

```
src\app\main.ts was not found. The "main.dev.ts" and "main.prod.ts"
[npm]             files have been deprecated. Please create a new file "main.ts" containing the content of "main.dev.ts", and
```

I would to know if there is a different way in ionic 5, or something else helpful

Answer (score 0):

Late but if you still need it, by looking at the docs you can hook your custom scripts to ionic serve

https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/configuration#hooks